# Converting a 2D array into an array of same size, but shaped as a 1D?

Tags: c

I am trying to convert the multidimensional array `table` into a monodimensional one without creating 2 monodimensional arrays. How can i do it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define ROWS 100
#define COLUMNS 100
int matrice[ROWS][COLUMNS];
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int rows = 0;
int columns = 0;
void table_creation(void);
void insert_data(void);

int main() {
table_creation();
i = 0;
j = 0;
while (i < rows) {
    j = 0;
    while (j < columns) {
        printf("\t%d ", table[i][j]);
        j++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    i++;
}
i = 0;
j = 0;
while (i < rows) {
    j = 0;
    while (j < columns) {
        printf("\t%d ", table[i][j]);
        j++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    i++;
}
}

void table_creation(){
i = 0;
j = 0;
do{
    printf("How many rows do you want?\n");
    scanf("%d", &rows);
} while (rows > ROWS || rows < 0);
do{
    printf("How many columns do you want?\n");
    scanf("%d", &columns);
} while (columns > COLUMNS || columns < 0);
insert_data();
}

void insert_data(){
i = 0;
j = 0;
printf("\nInsert numbers\n");
while (i < rows) {
    j = 0;
    printf("\n");
    while (j < columns) {
        printf("Insert the element in %d row and %d column\n", i ,j);
        scanf("%d", &table[i][j]);
        j++;
    }
    i++;
    printf("\n");
}
}
```

The output of this function are the number that are in the table. Now i want the same output but with a monodimensional array

Comment: I was thinking to do the multiplication of the rows and columns values and the result will be the max dimension of the unidimensional array

Comment: Did that not work when you tried it?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Not at all. I've applied this reasoning to the other functions too and the output isn't the one that i expect

Comment: If you have a 2-dimensional array of `m` rows and `n` columns, the equivalent flat array will have `m*n` values. Please post the code that isn't working.

Comment: The main problem is that `matrix` will always be `COLUMNS` columns wide no matter how many of those columns you are using. So if you are using fewer than `COLUMNS` columns, there will be unused elements at the end of each row in the memory layout, which makes it impossible to view the same memory as a 1-D array. (Using fewer than `ROWS` rows does not matter because the unused rows are all at the end of the memory layout and can be ignored.)

Comment: For varying row lengths read about [jagged arrays in C](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jagged-array-or-array-of-arrays-in-c-with-examples/).  This is not an often needed construct, nor commonly recommended, but available for certain applications,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addressing only the title question:

> *"convert the multidimensional array table into a monodimensional one without creating 2 monodimensional arrays. How can i do it?"*

Creating a 1D to match size of a 2D is easily doable, and updating the new array with contents of 2D is just as easy.  both can be done in a variety of ways.  Following shows some of them:

Given the following, creating a 1D can be done in multiple ways:

```
#define ROWS 5 (using smaller sizes for illustration)
#define COLS 3

int main(void)
{
    //simplest: 
    int matrix1[ROWS*COLS] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};

    //less simple, using variable length array:
    int matrice[ROWS][COLS];
    size_t elements = sizeof(matrice)/sizeof(int);//give number of int memory locations in 2D matrix
    
    //use count of int memory locations to create matrix of same size, but of different shape
    int newMatrix[elements];//note VLA cannot be initialized
    memset(newMatrix, 0, sizeof(newMatrix));//...its done in another statement. 

    return 0;
}
```

It is noteworthy that the memory layout for a 2D matrix such as `int matrice[ROWS][COLS];` is laid out in memory identically to that of a 1D matrix of the same size, eg `int matrice[ROWS*COLS];`.  Both exist in memory as 1 contiguous and sequential block.  So `matrix1`, `matrice` and `newMatrix` all conceptually look like this:

```
         | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 
 Rows    0     1     2     3     4      (each with 3 columns)
```

Also good to about [pointer offset notation](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/C/0200__Pointer/Pointeroffsetnotation.htm) i.e. that the expression `*(newMatrix + 0) = val;` is equivalent to normal array notation: `newMatrix[0] = val;`

And using this arrangement, and *pointer offset notation*, a 2D can be easily copied into a 1D using this, which copies 2D `matrix1` to 1D `newMatrix`:

```
for(int i=0;i<elements;i++)
{
     *(newMatrix + i) = *(matrix1 +i);
}
```

But even easier is to use [memcpy();](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_memcpy.htm).  The following copies 2D `matrix1` to 1D `newMatrix`

```
memcpy(newMatrix, matrix1, elements*sizeof(int));
```

Each of these methods copy the contents of memory with exactly the same result, i.e. in the same order, `row 0` appended by `row 1`, ..., appended by `row 4`

Note, VLAs are available in compilers compliant with C99, and optional other others since C99.  More on [variable length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)

Comment: Comment deleted.